# better alternative for this complex mysql query

Tags: mysql, select, group-by

I have two tables

```
1.fw_respondent_answers
2.fw_question_options
```

the structures are:

> fw_respondent_answers

```
id invitationid qdetailid optionid
1     2          1          1
2     2          2          2
3     2          3          3
4     3          1          4
5     3          2          5
6     3          3          6
```

> fw_question_options:

```
id optionname qdetailid
1   india        1
2   teacher      2
3   ok           3
4   france       1
5   assistane    2
6   good         3
```

**Desired Output:**

```
invitationid     country profession answer
    2            india     teacher   ok
    3            france    assistant good
```

**Explanation**:i want to get the `optionname` associated with a particular `invitationid` corresponding to the `qdetailid` and `optionid`.
`optionid` is the primary key of `fw_question_options`(id).

**what i have tried:**

```
SELECT distinct fra.`invitationid` ,fo.optionname as country,
fo1.optionname as profession,fo2.optionname as nps
FROM `fw_respondent_answers` fra,fw_question_options fo,
`fw_respondent_answers` fra1,fw_question_options fo1,
`fw_respondent_answers` fra2,fw_question_options fo2
WHERE fra.`optionid`=fo.id and fra.`qdetailid`=2 
and  fra1.`optionid`=fo1.id and fra1.`qdetailid`=1
and  fra2.`optionid`=fo2.id and fra2.`qdetailid`=3
```

**Question**:my above query is very slow.i just want to know is there any other better alternative to the above query?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: convert to proper joins. it's been over 20 years since `JOIN` was added to the sql standard. come on... get with the program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.invitationid, 
         MAX(IF(a.qdetailid = 1, b.optionname, '')) AS country, 
         MAX(IF(a.qdetailid = 2, b.optionname, '')) AS profession, 
         MAX(IF(a.qdetailid = 3, b.optionname, '')) AS nps
FROM fw_respondent_answers a 
INNER JOIN fw_question_options b ON a.optionid = b.id 
GROUP BY a.invitationid
```

Comment: thanks for the response.can u please elaborate why you are using MAX?

Comment: Note that CASE conforms to the SQL standard

Comment: @Mrcoder Try it without MAX/GROUP BY. It's basically a trick to avoid NULL results.

Comment: @Strawberry thanks for the comment but i am confused with the use of MAX here,kindly elaborate

Comment: saharsh +1 for the quick solution and will accept it in fe wminutes

Comment: @Strawberry its not giving proper result without max

Comment: That's why you need MAX :-)